# Guidance needed from all the experience people in this community.

Tags: contest-math, advice

Well I am preparing for the $\textbf{IMO}$ and I had this really small doubt actually. For geometry I'm basically following $\textbf{EGMO}$ ( I understand going thru it wont make me a pro but its certainly a good starting point isnt it?).

I am currently reading $\textbf{chapter 4 :assorted configurations}$ and its almost done. What i wanted to know was, which chapter should i do next?
Computational geometry is cool, but barycentrics seem cooler, and inversion seem even better while projective geo seems godly to me (scrolling thru the chapter i jus saw 3-4 line solutions nothing else like wowww). Soo well what should i do? Also i have done the theory part of complex numbers and most of the questions (no i cudnt do most but yeah i learned) .

If all among bary, inversion and projective are speicialized tools (which cant be used in a lot of problems i mean )than can i start with projective geo ? or is any one of these more versatile in your opinion? Or should i rather start computational geo? I am all ears for your advices n suggestions.

Also good if someone also suggest some good resources for algebra? Like $\textbf{OTIS excerpts}$ is good but it basically only covered inequalities and FEs. for example i came across this question while randomly scrollin thru 2016 SL and its problem A2. It is based as an inequality but isnt really one and id more algebraic-ish (idk how to explain cud u pls have a look?) and A6 and A7. Those arent FEs and inequalities. So where do i get some resources (theory n questions, precisely) for those kinda questions? Also is $\textbf{Pranav Srirams combi book}$ good?

I can do counting questions but obviously olympiad combi is much more different. Is that book a good starting point? I know these are a lot of questions but i really need some guidance right now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sriram's book is extremely advanced and I would not call it a starting point. The combinatorics problems in Engel's Problem-Solving Strategies is more of a starting point. For EGMO, what's stopping you from reading all of the remaining chapters? For algebra, once you know about functional equations, sequences and series, polynomials and inequalities all individually, the rest is a matter of applying these ideas to more specialized problems. Also, how come you didn't mention anything about number theory? Titu Andreescu has good books in that area, published by XYZ Press.

Comment: NT from Otis excerpts seems pretty good to me. After that ill just go through a handout or two and then start attacking the ISLs from 2000 ig (only for number theory, but ofc the whole thing should take a decent amount of time) Do you have any better strategy tho? As for EGMO the factor stopping me is TIME. I would like to get a bang for buck type deal. Do you think one can start projective geo without inversion or computational geo? Also tbh its not just about getting the knowledge i also like to finish off atleast a couple of questions from a chapter after reading it.

Comment: Would you suggest reading maybe 2 or more at once (Ofc id only ever choose an amount ill be able to manage)? In that case i would speed thru computational geo and bary together and then later inversion and projective geo together. Also as for Sriram's book i am finding it almost extremely understandable and till now stuff is makin complete sense and very logical (around pg 8) I get that this is just the beginning of the book but i feel like i cud definitely handle it. And since the book seems so well arranged and with nice examples, i dont really feel like switching books rn. What do u say?

Comment: as for algebra could you suggest some resources (except otis excerpts) (not introductory coz i well i feel i am certainly beyond that. Low to normal intermediate maybe?)? To me the best form of learning is through examples. That way i get to see how problems are approached and solved. Some resources with tons of examplew wud certainly be appreciated a lot. Right now my main problem seems to be resources for algebra... Lol as a side story i infact loved alg before starting my adventure and infact now m enjoying all the spheres which is very nice indeed.